# PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager: what is timeToLive attribute for?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient

I am trying to understand how does timeToLive attribute work?

Is this when you get a connection out of the pool, the time interval after which the connection is deliberately closed and returned to the pool?

[API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/nio/conn/PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.html#PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ConnectingIOReactor,%20org.apache.http.nio.conn.NHttpConnectionFactory,%20org.apache.http.config.Registry,%20org.apache.http.conn.SchemePortResolver,%20org.apache.http.conn.DnsResolver,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

I want my client that was using persistent connections to close every few seconds, so the requests to load-balancer are going to new server every few seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TTL parameter limits the total time to live of a persistent connection to a finite value. Regardless of keep-alive value returned by the server or client side keep-alive strategy a connection will never be re-used beyond its TTL.

One of the purpose of the TTL parameter is ensure a more equal redistribution of persistent connection across a cluster of nodes.

Comment: Based on the name of the attribute, I had the same impression. But it was hard to find documentation that confirms the same. Thanks for the info.